# Converting str to int in Python, only numbers w/o characters

Tags: python, type-conversion

I'm a beginner in Python and I can't find an answer to my problem. I have a file with some data and I want to get numbers from this file. My program looks like this:

```
class Mojaklasa:
def przenumeruj_pdb(self):
    nazwa=raw_input('Podaj nazwe pliku: ')
    plik=open(nazwa).readlines()
    write=open('out.txt','w')
    for i in plik:
        j=i.split()
        if len(j)>5:
            if j[0] == "ATOM":
                    write.write(j[5])
                    write.write("\n")
    zapis.close()
```

The 5th field in file has some numbers from -19 to 100, and it's working perfectly. But sometimes the 5th field has numbers with a letter, f.e. 28A and only want 28. Converting to int doesn't work. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

str.translate will remove any letters:

```
s = "10A"
from string import ascii_letters
print(int(s.translate(None,ascii_letters)))
10
```

Or use re:

```
import re
print(int(re.findall("\-?\d+",s))[0])
10
In [22]: s = "-100A"   
In [23]: int(re.findall("\-?\d+",s)[0])
Out[23]: -100

In [24]: int(s.translate(None,ascii_letters))
Out[24]: -100
```

I would also change your code a bit:

```
class Mojaklasa: # unless there are more methods I would not use a class 
    def przenumeruj_pdb(self):
        nazwa = raw_input('Podaj nazwe pliku: ')
        with open(nazwa) as plik, open("out.txt", "w") as write: # with will close your iles 
            for line in plik: # iterate over file object
                j = line.split()
                if len(j) > 5 and j[0] == "ATOM": # same as nested if's
                    write.write("{}\n".format(j[5].translate(None, ascii_letters)))
```

Comment: @sacma, the OP's input according to the question only has trailing letters but translate will still remove both A and g to leave just 10, re will also work

Comment: I think in all practical cases you are going to want `re` an easy list comprehension with `s.isdigit()` is possible but like translate you won't have any context.

Comment: @user3467349, the range is -19 to 100 so I am presuming whole numbers, isdigit will not keep the `-` where the regex and translate will.

Comment: Ah I missed the context, but if you wanted to preserve `-` you could use `not s.isalpha()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace a lot of logic with a properly formatted regular expression.

```
for i in plik:
    m = re.match(r'ATOM\s+.*?\s+.*?\s+.*?\s+.*?\s+(-?\d+)', i)
    if m:
        write.write(m.group(1) + '\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an overall-improved approach:

```
import re

class Mojaklasa:
    def przenumeruj_pdb(self):
        nazwa=raw_input('Podaj nazwe pliku: ')
        with open(nazwa) as plik, open('out.txt','w') as zapis:
            for i in plik:
                j = i.split()
                if len(j) <= 5: continue
                if j[0] == "ATOM":
                    mo = re.match(r'\d+', j[5])
                    if mo is None: continue
                    zapis.write(mo.group() + '\n')
```

I have not improved your choice of identifiers (except for some confusion between `write` and `zapis`), but improvements include (a) useful indenting, (b) use of `with` to open files (so they're automatically closed), (c) extraction of leading digits only via `re` (the one most germane to your Q), (d) use of `if/continue` lines rather than indenting (as "flat is better than nested").  Plus perhaps some I may be forgetting:-)

I **would** also recommend renaming `j` to `line` and `i` to `fields` (or whatever the equivalents in your chosen language) as `i` and `j` "sound" a lot like integer loop counters or the like, which is very confusing:-).